# How to debug queries to the DOM in Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-8, winjs

Can someone help me figure out the most suitable debugging features in visual studio for my problem below please. I'm coding in JS and have a line of code below

```
 listView = utils.query("#termTest");
 ui.setOptions(listView, {
            itemDataSource: publicMembers.itemList,
            itemTemplate:  utils.query(".itemtemplate"),
            oniteminvoked: this._itemInvoked,
 })
```

My application runs fine and doesn't cause an error however my data isn't being bound to that listview making me assume that for some reason it's not querying or finding the right element of the DOM. How do I found where it is actually pointing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the watch feature, rather than just mousing over?

You can set a variable in the watch window, right click it and set it to break when that value changes.

This should enable you to easily see when this value changes.